# VBA code required to Update exported Quickbooks Report

Tags: vba, excel, quickbooks

- My spreadsheet contains numerous Quick books exported reports.
- Normally by pressing the "Update Report" icon in the Excel Add-ons Quick books Tab a single report is updated.
- My client wants a button (VBA script) which will do the same task i.e updating sheets(Quickbooks Reports) in the spreadsheet.

My spreadsheet is called "Accounts" and the Sheet with Quickbooks Report is called "Annual Forecast".

The Quick Books file is called "DFG Ltd"

- I HAVE GOOGLED MANY SEARCH TERMS BUT SADLY STILL ABS NO IDEA HOW TO DO THIS?! As nothing has really come up, is this even possible. Your help is really appreciated.
  Thank You.

Comment: This isn't a free coding site, this is to help those having problems with programming languages. Try something, and if it doesn't work, then ask us _why_ - check [mcve] for more information

Comment: @MacroMan your comment is very assumptive that I haven't tried anything, couldn't be further from the truth. Endless Googling has lead no where, and if somebody in this fantastic community can shed some light or point in the correct direction where I can learn how to do this.  I'm always assisting and helping people in areas where i can help- I've never BLINDLY accused anyone of wanting free coding, based on just asking a question.

Comment: My criticism isn't in asking - none of us would learn anything without asking. My criticism is that you haven't asked your question _correctly_ in the context of this site. If you follow the link in my first comment you will see that this site is specifically based around answering questions based around _functioning_ code - as there is no actual code in your question and no example data/scenario then it is off-topic for this site as it is simply far too broad and not about a specific programming problem.

Comment: To add a little context, your question is a bit like asking a group of stunt pilots "How do I make the plane move off the ground?" - It's not a bad question per se - just far too broad a question and not specific enough to a particular topic or issue to be answered on this site.

Comment: @MacroMan No my apologises I've read your link and completely understand what you were trying to say, it makes sense.  I did initally have explanatory screenshots which I wanted to attached however my reputation isn't high enough. Regard I've added more specific details to my question?

Comment: Calling a spade a spade being mark down I'm guessing the question probably wont get seen.

Comment: Unfortunately, it probably won't get that many views due to the lack of code-specific problem(s) in the question. Stranger things have happened though so chin up.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you want to run code that exists in another add-in, you use `Application.Run`. Something like this:

```
Application.Run "QuickBooks.xlam!UpdateSheet"
```

If the addin was called QuickBooks.xlam (I don't know what it's called) and it contained a procedure called UpdateSheet (I don't know what the procedure is called).

There are a number of hurdles you will find trying to use this. I don't know if it works on COM addins and QB probably is one. Even if the addin is an Excel addin with VBA, it's probably protected so you can't open it to see what the procedure name is (although maybe you can break open the ribbon xml and see what the OnAction is set to).

If you can't get over those hurdles, you're probably stuck with SendKeys. You could send `Alt+Q+U` or whatever the sequence is to click the Ribbon button. Thankfully I haven't had to work with QB in a while, but if it steals the focus as much as it used to, SendKeys gets a little dangerous.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, i'm gonna try this now